# Answer number in "Related questions" list?

Tags: feature-request

When I look at the related questions list and see a zero, it always makes me think there are no answers, then when I go to answer it, I discover that it has already been answered. Therefore, I am requesting that the answer number is displayed as well as the vote number? EDIT: Also put in marks (e.g. duplicate or closed) as I cannot see if the question can actually be answered. Maybe even the date if possible?[image]

Comment: The numbers you have circled are the score of the question, not the number of answers. A green box means an answer was accepted by the asker.

Comment: @Dallium Yes, but I am requesting that there would be some other indication that a question has been answered for questions that do not have that green box, e.g. something like a little [a] to show that the question  already has an answer or [una] for questions with no answer.

Comment: What actual benefit does this provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that would benefit anyone.

What you are seeing is a list of ***related*** questions.  Green squares highlight an accepted answer, and the number shows the question score (i.e. assume high scoring questions more useful/researched than others).

Adding your proposed changes would:

- Require all stackexchange sites to also use the changes (for consistency)
- Alternatively, be different from all other stackexchange sites in its implementation
- Deviate from the real purpose of that list (i.e. it is a quick list of related questions to the question you have displayed on the left)
- More information needs more space (i.e. adds clutter)

You can see all the information you propose via:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions

You can filter the results (e.g. only show questions for a given game, only show unanswered questions etc).